# Place a comment on a specific post in PHP

Tags: php

I'm doing a project for school, it is some similar as Instagram.
So you can post a photo on your timeline and then other users can place a comment on this photo.

This comment option is succesfully done: You can place a comment and the comment comes into the database.

Comment classe: PHP code

```
public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue)
{
    switch($p_sProperty)
    {
        case "Comment":
            $this->m_sComment = $p_vValue;
            break;
    }      
}

public function __get($p_sProperty)
{
    $vResult = null;
    switch($p_sProperty)
    {
    case "Comment": 
        $vResult = $this->m_sComment;
        break;
    }
    return $vResult;
}


    public function Save() {
        $conn = Db::getInstance();
        //$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO comment(comment, postID, userID) VALUES(:comment)');
        $statement->bindValue(':comment', $this->Comment);
        $statement->execute();
    }

    public function GetRecentActivities($p_iPostID) {
        $conn = Db::getInstance();
        $allComments = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC;");
        return $allComments;
    }

}
```

But now the question is:
* Now the comment on a photo comes on every post and not on the specific post?
  In the URL of the post , i send a specific POSTID.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkJGL.png
How can i place the comment only on the post with the correct POSTID ?

Comment: Please add the query you use to select the spesific post with its comments

Comment: In your `GetRecentActivities()` method the query would be like this: `$allComments = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postID = '{$p_iPostID}' ORDER BY id DESC;");`

Comment: I know, i must use the where option in my query but the postid is not available in my database only in my URL.

Answer (score 0):

*In the answer I am assuming you use `GetRecentActivities` to get the comments for a post.*

I noticed you're not setting the `postID` field in the database, why is that? The `postID` field will help you map a post to a comment.Without it, you (and SQL) can't determine the context in which the comment was written. I'm sure you know how to add `postID` to the `INSERT` statement you provided, but for reference:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment, postID) VALUES (:comment, :postID)");
$stmt->bindValue(':comment', $this->Comment);
$stmt->bindValue(':postID', $this->PostID);
$stmt->execute();
```

In your SQL where you are calling `SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC;` you can add a `WHERE` clause to "filter" the data being returned. In your case this would be the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postID = <post_id> ORDER BY id DESC;
```

More information on what you can pass in your `SELECT` statement at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: I know, i must use the where option in my query but the postid is not available in my database only in my URL.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take in to account the new information. (I know it was originally in my question, didn't see you weren't setting `postID`)

Comment: This was also what i thought but the problem is the postID come not in my database.

Comment: I will send de postID from the URL to the database. Now there come only the comment in the databse.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking something right now? Did this solve your issue?